# angularjs MD-TAB return to the correct tab

Tags: angularjs, tabs

Hello I have created a system of tabs composed of 3 tabs.
From one of them I access a form, which is encunentra on another page and I need to press the return button to take me back to the correct tab but I can't figure it out.

**Code URL list.html**

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
  <md-tab label="tab1">
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="tab2">
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="tab3">
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

**Code form.HML**

```
<md-button ng-click="return()" class="md-raised">
   Cancelar
   <md-icon style="color: white;">restore_page</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

**Code .js**

```
    $scope.returnIdea = function(){;
            window.location.back();
     }
```

`Window.location.back` Takes me to the first tab but I want to go to the right tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `md-selected` in `md-tabs` to change the selected tab, you just need to pass the index, for yours it's 0,1 and 2: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs

> **md-selected**   (integer)    Index of the active/selected tab

```
<md-tabs md-selected="tabIndex" md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="">
  <md-tab label="tab1">
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="tab2">
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="tab3">
  </md-tab>
</md-tabs>

<md-button ng-click="back()" class="md-raised">
  Cancel
  <md-icon style="color: white;">restore_page</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

you can now create the back function by decrementing the index of the tab selected:

```
$scope.tabIndex = 0;
$scope.back = function() {
    if ($scope.tabIndex > 0) {
      $scope.tabIndex--;
    }
  }
```